# How to index a jsonb nexted column that uses Getpath operator #>> so we can a specfic value

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, postgresql-12

We have a jsonb column 'roller' as

```json
{
  "roller": {
    "dob": "8/16/1956",
    "ext": {
      "helio_status": ""
    },
    "grade": "11",
    "gender": "M",
    "sis_id": "3456704387",
    "location": {
      "zip": "99999"
    },
    "state_id": "546556560",
    "roller_number": "ASWE51460438"
  }
}
```

We pass a variable that we want to find in `{roller, sis_id}` to check if it exists

```
 u.roller#>>'{roller, sis_id}' = 'SE223dsd'
```

We created a gin index on roller but it does not work, it always does a seq scan on all of them.

Is there a specific type of index that will be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **always** look for that specific path, a regular B-Tree index is probably the best choice:

```
create index on the_table ( (roller#>>'{roller, sis_id}') );
```

You have to make sure that you always use the expression `roller#>>'{roller, sis_id}'` in your WHERE clause. Not something that is just equivalent like e.g. `roller -> 'roller' ->> 'sis_id'`

Comment: What if we need to do searches on state id or zip, do we need to create separate indexes for each